# Getting the average of a list of coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of coordinates like `[[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` in python, and I want to get the average of them, such as in this case is `[1, 1.66666666, 1.333333333]`. However, I can't quite figure out how to do that. I have tried NumPy and basic list manipulation but they all failed to work. Can someone help me? I am using `python 3.6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
data = [[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
average = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*data)]
print(average)
```

hope you're working with python 3.x.

Comment: Hi @Lena Oxton, your code will work properly on python 2 too :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use NumPy arrays for a column wise average as following. `axis=0` computes the average columnwise. You can also use `np.mean()` here

```
data =  np.array([[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]] )

averaged = np.average(data, axis=0)
print (averaged)
# [1.         1.66666667 1.33333333]
```

Comment: Sorry but that does not seem to work on this list: [[2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5]], it printed out [3.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665]. I want it to be a coordinate

Comment: `[3.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665]` is the correct answer. What else do you expect ?

Comment: Actually, OP wants an average of the column, not the row.

Comment: @mattsap: Oh that wasn't mentioned in the question so I thought it is listwise

Comment: sorry if I didn't clarify but I do want the average of the column, sorry about that

Comment: thank you that solved my problem, I will accept the answer after two minutes (I can't right now because there is a limit on SE)

Comment: @BrianZheng: You are welcome. One can also use lists here but NumPy makes life easier.